# Ajax data won't $_POST to php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have some Ajax code on one of my webpages:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function update(obj) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'php/process.php',
                method: 'POST',
        data: {
          orderID: obj.id
        },
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
```

I then have a page called "process.php" where I have this simple code:

```
<?php

  $orderID = $_POST['orderID'];
  echo $orderID;

?>
```

I have it so that when a button is pressed, the update() function is run using "onclick()". When I do click the button, i get the correct output in the browser console, but the page does not redirect to the process.php page. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: "but the page does not redirect to the process.php page". The point of AJAX is to change the content without reloading. if (data) is reported in your console, then all is working accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `type`, not `method`, to set a POST request. The default is GET, hence why your PHP receives no data. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'php/process.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    orderID: obj.id
  },
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

> When I do click the button, i get the correct output in the browser console, but the page does not redirect to the process.php page

That's the whole point of AJAX...

Comment: I changed it, I still get the same results as before though

Comment: If you mean that the page doesn't redirect, that's the entire point of AJAX

Comment: Ohh, I see. I will probably have a good read of Ajax, my understanding of what ajax does is quite wrong. Thanks for the answer though!